# Mathematical Mystery 2

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I am all around your everyday life

But you can't see me with eyes, like a hidden knife

I am made up of some of the most important numerals in town

Just take away imagination and these irrational clowns

Name this mathematical concept

Hint 1

> The first line is about computers and smartphones or any digital tech

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Binary

---

Edit:

I am all around your everyday life

> It's in your phone, it's in computers, it's in everything you use.

But you can't see me with eyes, like a hidden knife

> You can't see the individual bits that computers use, but it is important, like a hidden knife.

I am made up of some of the most important numerals in town

> Here the most important numerals are 0 and 1 (possibly i or e or pi could have claim to that position but the next line dissallows that)

Just take away imagination and these irrational clowns

> We don't care about imaginary numbers and irrational numbers, thus leaving us with only 0 and 1

Name this mathematical concept

> Binary is a mathematical concept

Comment: Correct, now you just have to explain the lines

Comment: @XavierStanton If you can I'd accept nikki's answer, they corrected it and added the solution before me.

Comment: I do accept the answer, and it looks like an explanation is coming on mobile in a little bit

Comment: @tox123 This answer hasn't been sufficiently explained.  You appear to have intended to update it, but never did.  Can you elaborate on your answer, please?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Oh wow I forgot, thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 5):

Is the answer

> Base system - binary?

I am all around your everyday life

> In all digital works

But you can't see me with eyes, like a hidden knife

> Can't really see the chips, they're too tiny

Most important numerals in town

> 0 and 1 are the numerals in binary town, 0... k-1 for town/system with base k

Comment: No. The fourth line says that imaginary numbers and complex numbers aren't present here

Answer (score 3):

I think it's

> The Hexadecimal Numbering system

I am all around your everyday life

> Hexadecimals are used in electronics and digital memory

But you can't see me with eyes, like a hidden knife

> Hexadecimal numbers are not directly visible, they're a group of 4 bits which in turn are electronic chips

I am made up of some of the most important numerals in town

> Binary numbers are arguably the most important numerals and hexadecimal numbers are groups of four binary digits.

Just take away imagination and these irrational clowns

> Hexadecimal numbers don't deal with irrational or imaginary numbers

Comment: No, but it is a number system

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking along the lines of

> $\mathbb{Q}$

Since

> The third and fourth lines suggest the set of numbers without the complex and irrational numbers. Maybe also the second line (can't see it with eyes ($i$)).

Comment: Unfortunately no, the hidden knife part is just for the rhyme

Comment: @XavierStanton Could you please point to the part of the question that makes this a wrong answer? If the only part is "that's not the answer I intended", then it would be a very good idea to add some more clues that explicitly exclude this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> sine?

I am all around your everyday life

> as sound waves

But you can't see me with eyes, like a hidden knife

> sound is not perceived with the eyes

Just take away imagination and these irrational clowns

> Made me think of fourier transform which is applicable to sound. Remove the complex part and I guess you get the magnitude of sine waves?

Comment: That is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

This is far-fetched, but are you maybe referring to a

> derivative

It is all around because

> differential equations are quite common in electronics

made up of some of the most important numerals in town

> the definition of a derivative: lim, 0, f(x)... all important concepts

Not sure about the "imagination and these irrational clowns", but neither complex nor irrational numbers are closely related with the definition itself.

Comment: Incorrect, but it is a good thought

Answer (score -1):

Is it

> Euler's identity, exp(i*pi) + 1 = 0

I am all around your everyday life

> Used all around us in laptops, phones etc for complex signal analysis

But you can't see me with eyes, like a hidden knife

> There is the component i, which makes it imaginary

I am made up of some of the most important numerals in town

> It involves e, pi, i, 1 and 0, the 5 fundamental concepts in Math

Just take away imagination and these irrational clowns

> The RHS of the equation is 0, "taking away" i (imaginary) and pi (irrational)

Comment: That is an amazing guess, but incorrect. You have to leave out e as well. It doesn't appear in the answer